# python easy_install or pip errors about sysconfig

Tags: python, pip

somehow the installation of python is broken in my linux OEL 6.9.

pip or easy_install are broken and I cannot do anything.

i get the same error on both sides:

```
# easy_install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 947, in <module>
    class Environment(object):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 951, in Environment
    self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 180, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-39.2.0-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 380, in get_build_platform
    from sysconfig import get_platform
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I removed python-setuptools to no avail.

I think i was trying to update latest version of pyOpenSSL and it crashed and cannot fix.

we are running Oracle enterprise Linux 6.6 in a VM.

how to fix it without resorting to installing python 2.7 which is not included in the official repos

thank you

Comment: BTW, Python 2.6 is no longer supported, so security updates are no longer released for it. And Python 2.7 will reach its official End of Life in 2020, so you need to seriously think about migrating to Python 3.

Comment: Note that [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sysconfig.html) doesn't exist in Python 2.6. It was introduced in Python 3.2 and backported to 2.7.

Comment: why is it complaining then that no sysconfig? perhaps it tried to upgrade a module that is not supposed to work on python 2.6 The OS does not offer any other option. 
how to remove the module causing python to complain about sysconfig.

Comment: What is your `setuptools` version atm? Did you install `python-setuptools` back after removal? It is vital for you to have it installed, otherwise you can forget about python packages.

Comment: Your problem is that `setuptools` dropped python 2.6 support since version 37, but it looks like you have version 39.2.0 for some reason. This will bork your python dist completely as you won't be able to install or uninstall anything, no matter `pip` or `easy_install`. This should be the primary issue to solve right now.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was:

remove completely `python-setuptools` and delete the folder from /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/.

then remove manually from the site-packages folder the module: pyOpenSSL it was after trying to upgrade it that everything went south.

```
rm -rf pyOpenSSL-18.0.0-py2.6.egg/
```

install back from yum `python-setuptools`  now pip list can list the modules and no more errors with `easy_install` either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so `setuptools` should be installed now - can you confirm you have the `pkg_resources.py` module? Run `ls /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py; echo $?`.

if this command outputs 0, remove the `pkg_resources package: sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/`.

Remove the dir only when the `pkg_resources` module is found! After that, pip should work again: run smth like `pip list` to check that.

**Else**

run:

`python3 -m ensurepip --default-pip`

`pip3 install [package]`